# Server side rendering not working in Laravel React project

Tags: reactjs, laravel, server-side-rendering

I am running Laravel 8.0 with React 17.0.2.

I am trying to implement SSR for optimizing the app. For that I am referring [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO42Kpa4pvI) which is using [this package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uO42Kpa4pvI) by spatie.

After setting up everything, I am getting the follwoing error

```
file_put_contents(../storage/app/ssr/9fa7979d88956cb5cc5019e5ee1fe73b.js): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: ../resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

There is a config file `ssr.php` where I need to defined node.temp path

```
'node' => [
    'node_path' => env('NODE_PATH', '/usr/local/bin/node'),
    'temp_path' => env('SSR_TEMP_PATH', storage_path('app/ssr')),
],
```

What should be this `temp_path` as there is no such directory called `ssr` in my app folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directory with the name `ssr` inside `/storage/app` and give it permission 777, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder inside app/ssr and there should be no space in any folder name of the path to the laravel project. I hope it will work for you.